# Multilingual bibliography using XeTeX, biblatex and polyglossia

Tags: biblatex, xetex, polyglossia

I am trying to write text in Russian language with some citations in Russian, English and German references using XeLaTeX + polyglossia + biblatex + biber. As a biblatex style I use [biblatex-gost](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatexgost/) which processes multilingual bibliographies fine with usual LaTeX + babel + bibtex, but the results in XeLaTeX are not so good - all fields are not localized.

My .tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}

\sloppy
\hyphenpenalty=10000

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguages{english, german}

\usepackage[%
            backend=biber,
            bibstyle=gost-numeric,
            language=auto,
            babel=other,
            sorting=ntvy,
            doi=false,
            eprint=false,
            isbn=false,
            dashed=false
                ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../bib/thesis.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text \cite{Gonzalez2002,Gonzalez2005ru}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

thesis.bib file:

```
@BOOK{Gonzalez2002,
  title = {Digital Image Processing},
  publisher = {Prentice Hall},
  year = {2002},
  author = {R. C. Gonzalez and R. E. Woods},
  pages = {793},
  edition = {2},
  language = {english},
  hyphenation = {english}
}

@BOOK{Gonzalez2005ru,
  title = {Цифровая обработка изображений : Пер. с англ},
  publisher = {М.: Техносфера},
  year = {2005},
  author = {Р. Гонсалес and Р. Вудс},
  pages = {1072},
  language = {russian}
}
```

The result pdf looks like this:
[image]

but should:
[image]

I've read that biblatex cannot work with polyglossia (at least it was so some time ago), but I hope there is a possible solution and would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

**UPD:** As a TeX-system I use TeXLive 2012.

Comment: The `babel=other` setting only works with `babel` loaded. A solution would require adding a `polyglossia` interface to `biblatex`. If you can't work with `babel` and `xecyr`, consider submitting a [feature request](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues).

Comment: I get `\edef\gostmedialanguage{russian}` when I try to compile Your document.

Comment: We have just submitted a potential fix for polyglossia support to the 2.8 DEV biblatex version on SF. Please try it and report any problems to the enhancement request here: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/69

Comment: Do you need to load first polyglossia or fontspec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authors should know better but as far as I know Biblatex does not officially support polyglossia (unfortunately). I use `Babel` with [xecyr](http://ctan.org/pkg/xecyr) which seems to work fine, although I've not tested it thoroughly.

**UPDATE:** Polyglossia support has been added to Biblatex since ver.2.8.